# Microsoft Excel Transpose Based on Date and Cell Value

Tags: excel, transpose

I've got raw data like this:

```
01-01-17    Cash Sales  1500
01-01-17    POS 1       50
01-01-17    POS 2       30
02-01-17    Cash Sales  6000
02-01-17    POS 1       150
02-01-17    POS 2       95
03-01-17    Cash Sales  6000
03-01-17    POS 1       150
04-01-17    Cash Sales  2700
04-01-17    POS 2       600
05-01-17    Cash Sales  1000
06-01-17    Cash Sales  7000
06-01-17    POS 1       1000
```

I'm trying to deduct the `POS 1` and `POS 2` sales of each day from the `Cash Sales` for that same day.

How can I achieve this in Excel?

I've looked up the `Transpose` function, but seems like that won't do for this.

The end results I'm trying to achieve are like below. Can you help?

```
                                    Cash Sales  POS 1   POS 2
01-01-17    Cash Sales  1500        1500        50      30
01-01-17    POS 1       50              
01-01-17    POS 2       30              
02-01-17    Cash Sales  6000        6000        150     95
02-01-17    POS 1       150             
02-01-17    POS 2       95              
03-01-17    Cash Sales  6000        6000        150 
03-01-17    POS 1       150             
04-01-17    Cash Sales  2700        2700                600
04-01-17    POS 2       600             
05-01-17    Cash Sales  1000        1000        
06-01-17    Cash Sales  7000        7000        1000    
06-01-17    POS 1       1000
```

Comment: Do you want the POS1 and POS2 also below cash sales? or just the cash sales for each day would be fine? (talking about second column)

Comment: The POS 1 and POS 2 are already in the RAW data. I'm trying to get them as seen in the second code block.

Comment: The output should be just to the right of the input as show, or want it in a different sheet?

Comment: Same sheet is fine...

Comment: It's in three columns as in the first code block (raw data). The second code block is the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know if it works,

Formula starting from `D2`, drag to right and drag down to the complete range,

`=IFERROR(IF(AND($B2=$D$1,INDEX($A2:$C$999,MATCH(D$1,$B2:$B$999,0),1)=$A2),INDEX($B2:$C$999,MATCH(D$1,$B2:$B$999,0),2),""),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This did the job :-)